# Correct projection for LAI Copernicus?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, hdf5

I download data from http://land.copernicus.eu/global/products/lai?qt-lai_characteristics=5  and when I visualize it in ArcGIS I set epsg 3857, but scale is wrong and measure show pixel with resolution 1x1m.

Can you tell me the correct system for this data?

Comment: It's listed under the technical tab for both the 300m and 1km versions. WGS84, AKA EPSG::4326.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the above comment, it is clearly defined in the [Technical Characterisitics](http://land.copernicus.eu/global/content/technical-characteristics-lai) as WGS84:

> **Projection and grid:**
>
> The product is displayed in a regular latitude/longitude grid (plate
>   carrée) with the ellipsoïd WGS 1984 (Terrestrial radius=6378km). The
>   resolution of the grid is 1/112°. The reference is the centre of the
>   pixel. It means that the longitude of the upper left corner of the
>   pixel is (pixel_longitude – angular_resolution/2.)

Comment: yes i know, but it is not resolve my problem. I need this raster project under my data but i do not know

Comment: which projection i need sed for correct visualisation, because epsg 4326 and 3857 are not good